# SFTP not working

Tags: unix, centos, sftp, vsftpd

I have a CentOS server where I have installed the vsftpd service, however I am getting the error

**bash: sftp: command not found**

Even the `which sftp` command can't find this service.

Detailed steps below :

*As root:*

```
yum install vsftpd
Total download size: 139 k  
Is this ok [y/N]: **y**
```

*Configure:*

```
vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Change `anonymous_enable=YES` to `anonymous_enable=NO`

Add `userlist_deny=NO` after `userlist_enable`

*Add allowed users:*

```
vi /etc/vsftpd/user_list
```

Replace contents with:

> `vsftpd userlist`
>   `userlist_deny=NO` so only allow users in this file
>   `user`

*Turn on Vsftpd service*

```
chkconfig vsftpd on
```

*Start the service*

```
service vsftpd start
```

Can someone help figuring out what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sftp` binary is provided by the `openssh-clients` package. Install that before:

```
yum install openssh-clients
```

then you can run `sftp`.

Comment: Thank you  ! Works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the vsftpd [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) is now running and can get through any firewall you have, you need to use an ftp [client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_(computing)) to connect to the server.

`yum install ftp`
`ftp x.x.x.x` <-- IP address of server

That will show that it is working. Remotely you will need a client such as [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/).